# Apache Storm performance issues running StanfordNLP bolts

Tags: stanford-nlp, apache-storm

So we have a bolt that would take data and try to parse it using StanfordNLP. Main objective is to identify entities, classify words in a sentence and try to find mentions. Here is a set up of the StanfordCoreNLP object. Notice that I am adding twitter model here as well.

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
    props.put("pos.model", "gate-EN-twitter.model");
    props.put("dcoref.score", true);
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

At first, it took a while to start up so we increased supervisor.worker.start.timeout.secs to 300 inside of conf/storm.yaml.

Now, while it runs it is just so slow... Plus, we are getting weird exceptions. Like this

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
>   at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:403) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
>   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:416) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
>   at edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder.funkyFindLeafWithApproximateSpan(RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder.java:418) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
>   at edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder.findSyntacticHead(RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder.java:346) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
>   at edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder.findHead(RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder.java:274) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
>   at edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder.extractPredictedMentions(RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder.java:100) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
>   at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.DeterministicCorefAnnotator.annotate(DeterministicCorefAnnotator.java:107) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
>   at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotationPipeline.annotate(AnnotationPipeline.java:67) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
>   at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.annotate(StanfordCoreNLP.java:881) ~[stormjar.jar:na]

Any best practices out there on how to set up StanfordNLP bolts inside of Apache Storm?

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, we just found out the reason for this exception. Seems like      pipeline.annotate(document); would break if there is a comma at the end of the document.

Comment: Above exception was caused since we were using 3.3.1 version of corenlp. Since upgrade to 3.4, exception was resolved

Comment: Try the shift-reduce parser if you want more speed in general....